# Baal HaTanya making kidush and a kvart of vodka

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, chabad, hasidic-story

I was told of a story about the Alter Rebbe in which once he did not have wine and cups during Shabbos day, and so he made kiddush on a quart of vodka.

What is the full story? Please give the most respected source of it.

Comment: That's a problem see Rama OC 183:2

Comment: @DoubleAA I am sorry, what part sposificly in the rama are you referring to? (The story I heard was that the kvort was full)

Comment: The Rama in OC 183:2. The text says וְיוֹצִיאֶנּוּ מִן הֶחָבִית לְשֵׁם בְּרָכָה (טוּר בְּשֵׁם רַשִׁ''י); וְנִרְאֶה דִּלְדִידָן שֶׁאֵין לָנוּ הַרְבֵּה יַיִן, אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ רַק לְשָׁפְכוֹ מִן הַקַּנְקַן שֶׁשּׁוֹמְרִים בּוֹ הַיַּיִן לְשֵׁם בְּרָכָה וְחָבִית לָאו דַּוְקָא, וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין בִּמְדִינוֹת אֵלּוּ. To say Kiddush on a whole bottle of wine, you'd have to pour it out and pour it back in LeShem Berakha (at least, lekhatchila) because the whole Heter to not be careful about filling the bottle leshem mitzva is because you're going to fill the cup leshem mitzva.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddush#Synagogue_kiddush This Wikipedia article says (without a source) that the Mishnah Berura allows an alcoholic beverage other than wine to be used during the Kiddusha Rabba. (Also mentions some Jews use a different alcoholic beverage during the Kiddusha Rabba.) Can anyone find this in the M''B?

Comment: The story is recorded here: http://www.beismoshiach.org/Ginsberg/ginsberg274.htm

Comment: I learned in seminary that he didn't have a vessel in which to make kiddush--I guess this was somewhere in remotest Russia--so he found a barrel or kvort or something, filled it with the only drink he had (vodka), and drank the rov kos. He was very ill, but his wife found him some charred beans or something which saved him from dying, presumably, al pi teva, by absorbing some alcohol from his stomach, or else causing him to vomit

Comment: The version I heard is that his in laws vehemently did not like his chassidik practices one of which was praying at length. So they would lock the wine cellar and cups when they were finished. He would show up only much later after they were well done and possibly asleep. Only having available to him some whatever chamar midinah was available he would have to make kiddish on that with whatever vessel was available which was a washing cup. Which he would use and make sure to drink more than half the cup. Which is used as a source that one should drink rov kos no matter how large the vessel.